# run an execution plan directly in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

is it possible to run an execution plan directly in PostgreSQL?

I did not find anything about it after quite some search in the PostgreSQL document and on the internet.

Comment: Not possible, you can only run SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to directly execute a query plan in PostgreSQL. You must run actual SQL.

In theory you could customise the PostgreSQL executor to accept plans without the corresponding SQL by feeding in plan trees. This would be a pretty big job and I'm sure there are many things that'd make it harder that I don't even know about.

You really need to just run SQL.

There is no reverse-compiler to turn an execution plan back into SQL.